# Array reference is somehow converted to a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, pass-by-reference, jquery-select2

I have a bunch of repetitive select2 elements, so I created little method to help set them up:

```
function setupDropDown(element, placeholderText, data) {
    $(element).select2({
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        placeholder: placeholderText,
        data: function () { return { results: data }; }
    });
}
```

So I might have a line of code like this:

```
 setupDropDown(MakeSelector, "Select a Make",  makes);
```

And 'makes' is a globally-scoped array that I want to be able to update:

```
 var makes      = [{ id: 0, text: "Dodge" }, { id: 1, text: "Chrysler" }];
```

I want to be able to change the makes array and have that instantly show up in the dropdown, but the changes don't show up. However, if I reference the global variable directly instead of through the 'data' parameter, it actually works fine. So the changed, working function might look like this:

```
function setupDropDown(element, placeholderText) {
    $(element).select2({
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        placeholder: placeholderText,
        data: function () { return { results: makes }; }
    });
}
```

What's going on here? Shouldn't the data parameter just contain a reference to makes? It's like it's being passed by value or deep copied at some point rather than copying the reference.

**UPDATE**

Okay, this fiddle shows the concept working: http://jsfiddle.net/kinetiq/8o85h8s2/

Now check out this fiddle, where I do the same thing, except the array is passed in through a parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/kinetiq/gp2bav4v/1/

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: It is because when you use an parameter.... initially both `data` and `makes` refer to the same object but when you say `makes = <new object>`, now `data` still refer to the old reference but `makes` refers to the new object

Comment: @ArunPJohny So what do I do here, wrap my object in another object so I can maintain a reference?

Or instead of saying makes = <new object> should I just be careful to say makes.clear, and then carefully add the items onto the end...? That would make what I'm doing more complicated.

Comment: I think wrapping it in another object will be good enough... like `makes = {src: <your array>}` then to update it use `makes.src = <new array>`

Comment: @BrianMacKay see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gp2bav4v/3/

Comment: another option is to modify the same array instance instead of changing it

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think this will be easiest - if you make an answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: @BrianMacKay sure... will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you use an parameter.... initially both `data` and `makes` refer to the same object but when you say `makes = <new object>`, now `data` still refer to the old reference but `makes` refers to the new object ...

One easy solution is to use another object to hold the array reference and pass the new object as the param like

```
var makes      = {src : [{ id: 0, text: "Dodge" }, { id: 1, text: "Chrysler" }]};

setupDrop('#selectMake', 'Select a Make', makes);

function setupDrop(element, placeholderText, contents) {
    $(element).select2({
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        placeholder: placeholderText,
        data: function () { return { results: contents.src }; }
    });
}  

$('#changeArray').click(function() {
    makes.src = [{ id: 0, text: "Buick" }, { id: 1, text: "Ford" }];
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gp2bav4v/3)

Comment: This is the best solution here, because it makes it so easy to get binding-style behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because your `element.select2` will be called only when you will call the function `setupDrop` So after changing the array the `element.select2` is not being called.

You have to call the function `setupDrop` after `makes` is being changed.Because here you are changing the reference of `makes` to another array, and the function has reference to older array.

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/gp2bav4v/2/)

Or one other solution don't change the reference of `makes` do something like bellow in `changeArray`

```
$('#changeArray').click(function() {
    makes[0] = { id: 0, text: "Buick" };
    makes[1] = { id: 1, text: "Ford" };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/gp2bav4v/4/)

Answer (score 1):

When updating the global array `makes`, `push` and `pop` values on and off instead of setting `makes`'s value to a new array instance. This way your `data` argument still retains reference to the original array.

```
while (makes.length) {
    makes.pop();
}
var newValues = [{ id: 0, text: "Buick" }, { id: 1, text: "Ford" }];
[].push.apply(makes, newValues);
```

Here's a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kavun/uwcxthy2/